# Ensure list contains only specific values

Tags: scala

How can I make sure a list only contains a specific set of items?

```
List[Int]
```

A function to make sure the list only contains the values 10, 20 or 30.
I'm sure this is built in by I can't find it!

Comment: Consider accepting an answer if you consider your question has been solved. If not, comment to the people helping to improve their answers to an acceptable level. It helps everybody.

Comment: You want to make sure that you can only add certain items to a list? that a list may only contain certain items while it exists or check that  a given list contains certain items at a given point in time. 3 Options with 3 different answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your question doesn't specify what you want to happen when the list doesn't contain the requisite items.

The following will return true if all the items in the List match your criteria, false otherwise:

```
val ints1: List[Int] = List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
val ints2: List[Int] = List(10, 10, 10, 10)

ints1.forall(i => List(10, 20, 30).contains(i)) // false
ints2.forall(i => List(10, 20, 30).contains(i)) // true
```

The following will return a List with only those items which matched the criteria:

```
val ints1: List[Int] = List(10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70)
val ints2: List[Int] = List(10, 10, 10)

ints1.filter(i => List(10, 20, 30).contains(i)) // List(10, 20, 30)
ints2.filter(i => List(10, 20, 30).contains(i)) // List(10, 10, 10)
```

Answer (score 3):

## forall

You may use `forall` with a Set containing elements which are valid or legal and you want to see in the list.

```
list.forall(Set(10, 20, 30).contains) //true means list only contains 10, 20, 30
```

## Set is Function

You need not use `contains` method as `Set` extends `Int => Boolean`. You can use Set like a function

```
list forall Set(10, 20, 30)
```

## Filter

You can use filter to filter out the elements which are not in the given list. Again you can use Set as function as Set extends Function.

```
list.filter(Set(10, 20, 30)).nonEmpty //true means list only contains 10, 20 and 30
```

## Collect if you like pattern matching

Collect takes a Partial function. If you like pattern matching just use `collect`

```
list.collect {
  case 10 => 10
  case 20 => 20
  case 30 => 30
}.nonEmpty //true means list only contains 10, 20 and 30
```

**Scala REPL**

```
scala> val list = List(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)
list: List[Int] = List(10, 20, 30, 40, 50)

scala> list forall Set(10, 20, 30)
res6: Boolean = false
```

Comment: The question is asking for how to verify that the list _only_ contains the values `10`, `20`, and `30`. To do so, we'd need to go one extra step and write something like `list.filterNot(Set(10, 20, 30).contains(_)).isEmpty` to verify that the list of elements that are not contained in that `Set` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

If you simply want to determine whether all of the values in your list are "legal", use **forall**:

```
def isLegal(i: Int): Boolean = ??? // e.g. is it 10, 20, or 30
val allLegal = list forall isLegal
```

If you want to trim down your list so that only legal values remain, use **filter**:

```
val onlyLegalValues = list filter isLegal
```

Note that a `Set[Int]` counts as a `Int => Boolean` function, so you could use that in place of your `isLegal` method:

```
val isLegal = Set(10, 20, 30)
val allLegal = list forall isLegal
val onlyLegalValues = list filter isLegal
```